# Messages are spooled but not sent

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using symfony2 with swiftmailer to send some sample messages, but it doesn't work, messages are spooled in symfony/app/cache/swiftmailer/spool but when i do the commande php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send the messages are deleted from the spool but are not sent, the output in the console is: sent 0 emails, someone can tell me where is the problem ?here is my config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:            smtp
    username:             ~
    password:             ~
    host:                 localhost
    port:                 false
    encryption:           ~
    auth_mode:            ~
    spool:
        type:                 file
        path:                 "%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool"
    sender_address:       ~
    antiflood:
        threshold:            99
        sleep:                0
    delivery_address:     ~
    disable_delivery:     ~
    logging:              "%kernel.debug%"
```

and here is my code:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('test@gmail.com')
    ->setTo('myadress@gmail.com')
    ->setBody($this->renderView('ProjetAccountBundle:Main:email.txt.twig'))
;
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);

return $this->render('ProjetAccountBundle:Main:test.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the use of smtp instead of mail, the correct configuration file for me was this:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:            mail
    username:             ~
    password:             ~
```

Comment: That's not why your messages were spooling. It had to do with however smtp was configured.

Answer (score -2):

swiftmailer:

```
spool: { type: memory }
```

You need to remove this.